# htaccess and jquery load issue

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

i have my htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.haluze.eu$
RewriteRule (.*) http://haluze.eu/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^najnovsie/(.*) index.php?s=new$1
```

and my php script which loads with jquery another script.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#responsecontainer").load("./script/script_profile_msg_read.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>&strana=<?php echo $strana ?>");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      jQuery("#responsecontainer").load('./script/script_profile_msg_read.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>&strana=<?php echo $strana ?>');
   }, 30000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

if i access site like for example domain.com/index.php?s=new its ok
but when i access site like nice url domain.com/najnovsie/ my php script is not showing.

could you please help me?
sorry for english

Comment: What does that have to do with your JavaScript / jQuery function?

Comment: What is the location of above .htaccess file? Is it in DocumentRoot or in some other sub directory?

Comment: its in the root directory where is the index.php file

Comment: sory... i already fixed it... i had wrong path to include jquery.js :P
slash / was needed in the begining of path.

thanks anyway :)
and sorry :D